# Multiple decorators wrapping a generator function in python 3.7 - all possible coin combinations problem

Tags: python, generator, python-decorators

I want to write a program that shows all the possible ways a combination of different coins (5c, 10c, 50c, etc.) can amount to a certain value (for instance, $4). Let's say, for starters, I only want to consider 50c, $1 and 2$ into the possible combinations. If I want to use brute force, I could write 3 nested `while` loops and return that combination of currency every time they sum up to the value I want (in this case, $4). However, as we consider more currency options (for instance, 1c, 5c, 10c, 25c, 50c, $1, $2, $5, $10, $50, $100) and bigger sums (let's say I want all combinations to get $400), the code becomes very verbose and difficult to mantain. If I want to make a generic algorithm that works for any country and combination of currencies, I can't rely on simple loop nesting.

Given this problem, I've tried using decorators so I can nest the loops in a single function:

```
INTENDED_SUM = 400

coin_count = {
    200: 0,
    100: 0,
    50: 0,
}

def max_range(value):
    return INTENDED_SUM / value

def coin_loop(coin_value):
    def decorator(func):
        while coin_count[coin_value] <= max_range(coin_value):
            yield from func()
            coin_count[coin_value] += 1
        else:
            coin_count[coin_value] = 0
    return decorator


@coin_loop(100)
def get_combinations():
    agg = sum([i * coin_count[i] for i in coin_count])
    if agg == INTENDED_SUM:
        yield coin_count

for i in get_combinations:
    print(i)
```

This is the output:

```
{200: 0, 100: 4, 50: 0}
```

However, if I add multiple decorators to the `get_combinations()` function, a TypeError is raised:

```
@coin_loop(200)
@coin_loop(100)
@coin_loop(50)
def get_combinations():
    agg = sum([i * coin_count[i] for i in coin_count])
    if agg == INTENDED_SUM:
        yield coin_count

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "31-coin_sums.py", line 29, in <module>
    for i in get_combinations:
  File "31-coin_sums.py", line 15, in decorator
    yield from func()
TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
```

So I have two questions:

1. Why does get_combinations already shows up as a generator and does not need to be called when I call it in the last 2 lines of the code? Shouldn't they be like this?

   ```
   for i in get_combinations():
       print(i)
   ```
2. Why isn't decorator nesting working in this case? Expected output should be something like:

   ```
   {200: 2, 100: 0, 50: 0}
   {200: 1, 100: 2, 50: 0}
   {200: 1, 100: 1, 50: 2}
   {200: 1, 100: 0, 50: 4}
   {200: 0, 100: 4, 50: 0}
   {200: 0, 100: 3, 50: 2}
   {200: 0, 100: 2, 50: 4}
   {200: 0, 100: 1, 50: 6}
   {200: 0, 100: 0, 50: 8}
   ```

EDIT: just as an example, I want the code above (with multiple decorators) to be equivalent to this, except without nested `whiles`:

```
INTENDED_SUM = 400

coin_count = {
    200: 0,
    100: 0,
    50: 0,
}

def max_range(value):
    return INTENDED_SUM / value

def get_combinations():
    while coin_count[200] <= max_range(200):
        while coin_count[100] <= max_range(100):
            while coin_count[50] <= max_range(50):
                agg = sum([i * coin_count[i] for i in coin_count])
                if agg == INTENDED_SUM:
                    yield coin_count
                coin_count[50] += 1
            else:
                coin_count[50] = 0
            coin_count[100] += 1
        else:
            coin_count[100] = 0
        coin_count[200] += 1
    else:
        coin_count[200] = 0

for i in get_combinations():
    print(i)
```

Comment: I don't understand what function your multiply-decorated function serves.

Comment: I'm sorry, my code is a bit confusing. Each decorator should loop through 0 and the max possible coins of a given value (50c count shouldn't go further than 8 in this case) while calling the loop on other values and also testing if the sum of the coins add up to $4 (in this example). It should yield the dictionary of coin counts everytime they add up to that value.